# Unable to Edit Text in Fabric.js Table Cells

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fabricjs

I'm working on a project where I'm using Fabric.js to create a table with **editable **text in each cell. I'm able to create the table, move, and resize it, but I'm facing an issue with editing the text in the cells.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
function createTable(rows: number, cols: number, cellWidth: number, cellHeight: number) {
  const table = new fabric.Group([]);

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      const cell = new fabric.Rect({
        width: cellWidth,
        height: cellHeight,
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        selectable: false,
        left: j * cellWidth,
        top: i * cellHeight,
      });

      const text = new fabric.Textbox(`Cell ${i + 1},${j+1}`, {
        left: j * cellWidth + 5,
        top: i * cellHeight + 5,
        fontSize: 16,
        width: cellWidth - 10, // Adjusting for padding
        height: cellHeight - 10, // Adjusting for padding
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        editable: true,
      });

      table.addWithUpdate(cell);
      table.addWithUpdate(text);
    }
  }

  return table;
}

const table = createTable(+rows, +cols, +cellWidth, +cellHeight);
canvas?.add(table);
```

I've set `editable: true` for the textboxes, but I'm still unable to edit the text in the cells. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the actual behavior?  "It doesn't work" isn't useful to help in debugging

Comment: I apologize for the vague description. The specific issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to edit the text in the cells of the table. I've set editable: true for the textboxes, but they still don't respond to editing. Any suggestions on what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution.
You have to add the following code:

```
const table = new fabric.Group([]);
table.evented = true;
table.subTargetCheck = true;
```

You have to add the following code to each text in the loop:

```
var dirtyGroup = function() {
  text.group.dirty = true;
  canvas.renderAll();
};
text.on("changed", dirtyGroup);
text.on("editing:exited", dirtyGroup);
text.on("selection:changed", dirtyGroup);
```

and also you have to figure out what method you will use to exit editing using the `text.exitEditing()` method;